# pc817 large emiter collector voltage drop in saturation

Tags: power-supply, led, opto-isolator, optoelectronics

I'm experimenting with a very simple circuit with a PC817 optocoupler. I just want to turn on an LED with the optocoupler output, but the bright is really low in comparison to a direct drive of the LED.

Here's my circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flbmNo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem I'm experiencing is a large colector-emiter voltage drop (around 2.8V), when the datasheet states voltages below .5V for my setup.

Is there something wrong with my circuit?

Thanks

Comment: What is the LED part #?

Comment: It's a regular 5mm red LED. When I short the leads C and E (3 and 4) of the opto, the LED is noticeably brighter (I'd say twice as much). Thanks

Comment: I just measurd my forward current and it's 19mA

Comment: OK so.... voltage across D2 will be ~2V without Q1 that's only 3.33ma. Q1 at 3.33ma Vce is ~ 1V. It's not really any wonder it's so dim. you need to reduce that resistor to like 60R.

Comment: Ok I understand. I'll try tomorrow as 390 is the lowest R i have right now. Thanks for your help

Comment: With 20mA input it should drop less than 0.5V at the current your LED would be drawing. So either the optocoupler is faulty, or the output polarity is reversed (ie. Collector and Emitter swapped) which would produce a very low CTR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expound further on Trevor's answer: For any optocoupler application you have two circuits to work on. First, ensure that the signal side (infrared LED of the optocoupler) has sufficient current to operate. Then calculate that the driven side sinks enough current to operate the load.

The maximum current \$I_{F1}\$ allowed through \$D_{1}\$ is 50mA (in the [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/73758.pdf), Absolute Maximum Ratings: Forward current). Choose a convenient value half of that (factor of safety of 2): \$I_{F1} = 20mA\$. **Figure 7** from the datasheet shows that forward voltage \$V_{F1} \approx 1.3V\$ if operating at \$I_{F1} = 20mA\$ and ambient temperature of 25C.

Finding for the value for the current limiting resistor for the optocoupler LED:

\$R_{1} = \frac{V_{1} - V_{F1}}{I_{F1}} = \frac{3.3V - 1.3V}{20mA} = 100\Omega\$

Typical 5mm diameter discrete LEDs are driven at 20mA to be "bright enough". Voltage drop across LED load will vary by color so consult its datasheet or this [handy chart](http://www.oksolar.com/led/led_color_chart.htm). Let's assume that \$D_{2}\$ is a green LED that drops \$V_{F2} = 2.0V\$ at \$I_{F2} = 20mA\$. Rearrange your circuit so that \$R_{2}\$ is feeding from positive terminal of voltage source \$V_{2}\$ so that \$V_{E}\$ of \$Q_{1}\$ is conveniently 0V. Given that \$I_{F2} = I_{R2} = I_{C} = 20mA\$, and \$I_{F1} = 20mA\$, **Figure 6** gives us voltage drop of \$Q_{1}\$ as \$V_{CE} \approx 1.9V\$. Voltage that \$R_{2}\$ needs to drop is:

\$V_{R2} = V_{2} - V_{F2} - V_{CE} = 3.3V - 2.0V - 1.9V = -0.6V\$

Clearly, we do not have enough voltage to supply the LED!

There are several ways to get around this:

1. increase \$V_{2}\$
2. choose a lower drop LED color, or
3. decrease \$V_{CE}\$ by increasing \$I_{F1}\$ (increasing the base signal to increase collector current)

Assuming we can only change \$I_{F1}\$: choose \$I_{F1} = 30mA\$. **Figure 6** now gives us \$V_{CE} = 1.2V\$: so, \$V_{R} = 3.3V - 2.0V - 1.2V = 0.1V\$. That means the limiting resistor resistance is merely \$R_{2} = \frac{0.1V}{I_{F2}} = 5\Omega\$. That's a \$4.7\Omega\$ or \$3.9\Omega\$ resistor if using the E12 series.

Now go back to the signal side and adjust \$R_{1}\$. At \$I_{F1} = 30mA\$, **Figure &** gives \$V_{F1} \approx 1.35V\$. So \$R_{1} = \frac{3.3V - 1.35V}{30mA} = 65\Omega\$. That's a \$56\Omega\$ E12 resistor.

If you have noticed, we are now operating \$D_{1}\$ closer to its limits. Also if \$V_{1}\$ or \$V_{2}\$ is a battery, we are dropping a lot of energy to waste. If we can minimize \$V_{CE}\$ (and \$I_{F1}\$), we could improve both. One way to do this if your application for the optocoupler is to merely switch on/off the load is to use a FET output optocoupler instead.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to figure out how hard you want to drive that LED, i.e how many mA.

Once you do, view the specifications of the device to get the forward voltage at that current. If you do not have access to the spec sheets, set that current across the LED and measure the forward drop and add say 10% for a tolerance.

Lets say you chose \$I_{LED} = 15mA\$ and find the LED drop of \$V_{LED} = 1.75V\$

Now look at this chart in the opto-coupler specifications.

[image]

You say your LED drive is \$\approx $20mA\$ so look at that line on the chart.

Look for \$15mA\$ up the left axis and find where that crossed the \$20mA\$ IF curve. Then drop that down to the bottom axis.

That gives you a \$V_{CE} \approx  0.9V\$

This means the voltage you need to drop across the resistor is...

\$V_R = 3.3 - V_{LED} - V_{CE} = 3.3-1.75-0.9 = 0.65V\$

Resistor required = \$V_R/I_{LED} = 0.65/.015 \approx   43\Omega\$

Comment: I believe you are looking the the wrong axis. \$I_{F}\$ on the chart is for the optocoupler's infrared LED \$D_{1}\$. For the load in series lookup the driven current as \$I_{C}\$.

Comment: @shimofuri sorry mate that's the curves for the transistor at specific LED currents.

Answer (score 0):

You can drive up to 50mA absolute max input current and 50mA output current but CTR is only 50%. for cheap versions but better suffix models are CTR=600%

- **or hFE from 0.5 to 6 (TYP)**  DEPENDING ON GRADE OF PART denoted by suffix.

Thus for 1.2V IR at high current on input and 2.2V on output LED

From memory...

R1 = (3.3 - 1.2)/40mA = 52 Ohms approx.

R2= (3.3 - 2.2)/20mA = 55 ohnms

- use same R for Red LED and adjust R2 if CTR is better than normal and check V(R2) /R2 = I2

Comment: The real answer of course is to use a digital opto-isolator rather than a transistor based opto-isolator with limited CTR.

Comment: I only explained the problem , I think no isolator at all for an LeD with reverse diode for PLT noise is the better solution

Comment: @JackCreasey could you please recommend a cheap digital opto? I've never used one before. Thanks

Comment: @AwerMuller. Sure......The H11L1 is about the cheapest Digital Opto I know of: http://www.everlight.com/file/ProductFile/H11L1.pdf Readily available from Digikey or Ebay.

Comment: @AwerMuller  FYI that CMOS Opto is like open drain with 100K~1M pullup so it is designed to sink current up to 50mA Absolute max 3~15V but has RdsOn in the 50 Ohm range +/25% reduces with Vcc  with input hysteresis with 1.2V @ 20mA IR diode. So the current gain is is greater and cleaner output than an opto diode or opto transistor, but nonlinear compared to  an opto diode

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 All digital gates etc are non-linear, why do you see this as some sort of problem? If you require a linear transfer ratio, you'd know so would select the right sort of component surely?

Comment: opto PD's have a tighter tolerance due to linearity and no 300% tolerance on hFE although CTR is lower, when one does worst case tolerances of Opto's in 100k volume/yr. this is a consideration with worst case tolerances of all variables. Been there, dun that  but the Schmitt logic output is a great solution at slight cost impact. or 0.32 (5k) in hi-vol when pennies and both tolerance count